# Using throttle with Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, lodash, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I use lodash in a Vue 3 project, when I try to use the `_.throttle` in the `setup` function, it doesn't work. I writed a demo in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hsxhye?file=src/App.vue).

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="handleClick">Click</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from 'lodash';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {
    const handleClick = () =>
      _.throttle(function () {
        console.log('hi');
      }, 2000);

    return {
      handleClick,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I have a solution now. My companion said that omit the `() =>`  can fix it, add the `{ trailing: false }` is better.

```html
const handleClick = _.throttle(function () { console.log('hi'); }, 2000, { trailing: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing to run the throttled function by adding the `()` :

```
  const handleClick = () =>
      _.throttle(function () {
        console.log('hi');
      }, 2000)();
```

or assign it to a variable then run it :

```
  const handleClick = () =>{
     let throttled= _.throttle(function () {
        console.log('hi');
      }, 2000);
     
     throttled();
   }
```